# Calcular edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento con funciones javascript

Tags: javascript

Buen día, tengo estas 2 funciones y lo que deseo es obtener la edad de una persona. Ahora, lo que estoy haciendo es ver mediante alertas la fecha de cumpleaños de una persona y de la otra ver la fecha actual, ahora a partir de eso, luego de ingresar en mi input la edad, que este me muestre cuantos años tengo. Quizás habría una forma correcta para poder obtener relacionar la variable yyyy y year?, si estoy confundido, lo entenderé, recién empiezo y quiero aprender, gracias.

```
function vuelveFecha(fecha){
//Si la fecha no es 10 caracteres se devuelve nom�s
if (fecha=="" ||fecha==null ){
        return fecha;
}
if(fecha.length < 10){
    alert(m_0167);
    return fecha;
}
    var strDate = fecha;

    var dd   = strDate.substring(0,2);
    var mm   = strDate.substring(3,5);
    var yyyy = strDate.substring(6,10);
    strDate  = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

    alert(strDate);
    return strDate;

    }

function calcularEdad(){
    var f = new Date();
    day = f.getDate();
    month = f.getMonth()+1;
    year = f.getFullYear();

    if(day<10)
        day='0'+day;
    if(month<10)
        month='0'+month;

    fecha = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;

    alert("Hoy es : "+fecha);
    alert("el anio es: "+year);
}
```

Mi input es este:

```
<input name="txtFecNacimiento" style="width: 75" tabindex="9" 
onBlur="this.value=vuelveFecha(this.value); calcularEdad()" value=" 
<fmt:formatDate value='${bean.dateFechaNacimiento}' pattern='dd/MM/yyyy'/>" 
maxlength="10" onfocus="this.select();nextfield='cboSexo'" <%= strEstiloCe 
 %>>
```

Comment: Pero que llevas intentado, la edad la calculas usando la fecha actual y fecha de nacimiento, pero no veo que hayas hecho algo, iintenta una solucion y especifica que problema tienes, remormulando tu pregunta.

Comment: @MiguelZarate sí, tienes razón, lo que quiero hacer es declarar una variable edad y sobre esta restarle yyyy - year y me obtenga la edad que tengo. (edad=yyyy-year). Mi problema es que cuando lo mando por un alert(edad), este no me bota nada, y creo que es porque están en funciones diferentes, entonces quisiera saber como puedo hacer. No sé si me dejé entender un poco, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas dejo por aquí código para hacerlo en JS puro si aún interesa.

```
function calcularEdad(fecha) {
    var hoy = new Date();
    var cumpleanos = new Date(fecha);
    var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleanos.getFullYear();
    var m = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleanos.getMonth();

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < cumpleanos.getDate())) {
        edad--;
    }

    return edad;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Y si colocas el input como date, lo tendrías así. creo que sería facil a partir de ahi implementar lo que deseas.

Según la fecha que introduzca verificas su edad y la muestras en otro input.

```js
$(function(){
            $('#birthday').on('change', calcularEdad);
        });
        
        function calcularEdad() {
            
            fecha = $(this).val();
            var hoy = new Date();
            var cumpleanos = new Date(fecha);
            var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleanos.getFullYear();
            var m = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleanos.getMonth();

            if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < cumpleanos.getDate())) {
                edad--;
            }
            $('#age').val(edad);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday" value="">
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pero estás agregándole JQuery, como haría con javascript puro, el proyecto que tengo ya está implementado años y no tiene jquery en sus librerías.

Answer (score 0):

Obtén la fecha de nacimiento conviértala a Date() y réstasela a la fecha de hoy, eso te dará la diferencia en milisegundos, entonces lo conviertes de milisegundos a años y listo

```
var fechaDeNacimiento = new Date('1995-08-11');
var hoy = new Date();
console.log(parseInt((hoy - fechaDeNacimiento) / (1000*60*60*24*365)));
```