# calcular la edad a partir de una fecha de nacimiento y mostrarlo en el siguiente input de manera automática. Html y Js

Tags: javascript, html

- Una vez con el form como puedo hacer la función en js para tener la
  edad automática en input de edad partiendo de la fecha de nacimiento obtenida en el input anterior?

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento">
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Edad" placeholder="Edad">
</div>
```

Comment: Ya probaste usando `value=""`??

Comment: Ya hay preguntas de este tipo, [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/251005)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.